# PHP run through entire page, grab all links

Tags: php, curl

Ive written this script, and it works, but only grabs the first link on the page, then stops:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("localurls.csv","r");
while(($line=fgetcsv($handle))!==FALSE) {

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $line[0],
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$regex_body = '%<a href="(.+?)">%s';
$myBody = preg_match($regex_body, $resp, $matches);
$myFile = "localdownload.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $matches[0]);
fclose($fh);
sleep(2);
}
?>
```

The .csv file is a list of the pages Im having the script crawl.
When I run this, I get the first link on each page.. I.E.

```
<a href="www.google.com">
```

then I have it written to a txt file.
Would anyone know a way to modify this to continue to look on the page for ALL iterations of code between

```
<a href="
```

AND

```
">
```

Ive thought about it, and looked online for how this might be accomplished, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`. `preg_match` returns the first occurrence, `preg_match_all` performs a **global** regex and searches for all instances.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: was that easy eh??  Thank you very much.

Comment: when I made this change, it writes "Array" to the txt file.. Do i need to explode the array somehow before writing to the txt file?

Comment: If you are looking to just dump the information to the file you can use print_r(matches[0]) like this `fwrite($fh, print_r($matches[0]));`

Comment: Apologies, that actually may not work. You will need to loop through the matches and write them.